# Gradle Inject Build Environment into WebApplicationInitializer

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, gradle

I am trying to build my project using a build profiles (dev, test, or prod). I have a spring web application that I am initializing using my implementation of WebApplicationInitializer.

```
public class WebMvcInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) {
        configureSpringDispacher(servletContext);
        configureLogging(servletContext);
    }

    public void configureSpringDispacher(ServletContext container) {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.register(WebMvcConfigurer.class);
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispacher = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(context));
        dispacher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispacher.addMapping("/");
    }

    private void configureLogging(ServletContext servletContext) {
        servletContext.setInitParameter( "log4jConfigLocation" , "file:/${env}-log4j.properties" );
        Log4jConfigListener log4jListener = new Log4jConfigListener();
        servletContext.addListener( log4jListener );
    }
}
```

There, I am trying to configure logger (log4j) using ${env}, which I want to replace with dev-log4j.properties or prod-log4j.properties, depending on how I build my project.

In my build.gradle, I have:

```
processResources {
    from('src/main/java') {
        filter ReplaceTokens, tokens:[
            "env": project.getProperty('env')
        ]
    }
}
```

Finally, I am building the proeject using:

gradle clean build -Penv=prod

My placeholder ${env} does not get replaced. If I trying doing the filtering in xml or properties files, it works fine. I understand that logging might not be the most important property to configure, but I might want to also use similar approach to registering environment-specific Spring configurer.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps not the answer to your question, but have at look at [Spring Profiles](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html). Using Gradle for processing and replacing doesn't feel good.

Comment: Filtering sources is definitely not a good idea. As @alexvetter suggested use spring profiles or filter resources.

Comment: Thanks for commends. I discarded the idea of filtering sources. I have never used Spring Profiles, but it seems like it is a neat feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up filtering spring.properties file and then reading that from my WebApplicationInitializer to activate Spring Profile.

This appears to be a better solution than trying to filter the sources.